# Email weekly reminder to group

Tags: email, scheduled-reminders

Is there a way to schedule the same email to a group each week?  It's a reminder for a meeting we run.

Steve

Answer (score 4):

Could be done with scheduled reminders
Adminster -> Communications -> Scheduled Reminders

Entity -> Event Name, choose first meeting name.

Enable repetition
Repeat every 7 days until 10 years after event start date

(or something like that).

Comment: Can a repeating scheduled reminder be created without linking it to an event or other activity? I just want to start a recurring email starting [now].

Answer (score 1):

The [scheduledcommunication](https://github.com/sgladstone/com.fountaintribe.scheduledcommunication) extension might help.

Once installed, you have to add a new Scheduled Reminder that uses the API call `Email2Each.Sendemails`, with parameters:

```
group=Name of the group
message_template=name_of_the_template
```

The group can also be a smartgroup (so people could update their preferences to change a value of a custom field to stop receiving the messages, for example).