# Schedule a Recurring Email to Everyone in a Group

Tags: civirules, mailing

Is it possible to send an email to a group once a week?  I can see that scheduled reminders can be sent based on an entity but I'd like to send an email invite to all our members that haven't already booked into our events.

I have set upa a group that contains only those members who haven't signed up for the event - this is a mailing list.

I don't really have any trigger for it as such but need it to go weekly for a few weeks.

Civi crm 5.53 - wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

This [past question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/7956/email-weekly-reminder-to-group) covers some options.

Scheduled reminders are not necessarily easy to work with and can be a little anxiety-inducing, in my experience. Another option would be CiviRules. There is a Daily trigger for group members, but no weekly trigger. It would be easy to add a weekly trigger to the extension with very little code (or pay someone to add it).